# ¿Cómo bloquear la dirección de una carpeta UPLOADS?

Tags: php, .htaccess

¿Cómo puedo bloquear una carpeta para que no vean los archivos? ¿Cómo se puede hacer eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mejora la escritura, por favor.

Comment: lo se ecribo muy rapido

Comment: No, no escribes rápido. Escribes mal.

Answer (score 2):

La manera mas sencilla es colocar en esa carpeta un archivo con nombre **index.html** sin contenido. De esta manera, al momento de colocar la dirección web o URL en tu navegador, se renderizará el archivo por defecto, el cual es el index.html. Esta opción funcionará para la carpeta UPLOAD, pero no funcionará para las subcarpetas.

Para ocultar todas las carpetas que estén en esta condición, puedes modificar el archivo de configuración del apache (httpd.conf), agregando el modificador **-Indexes** o eliminando el modificador **Indexes**, si existe.

Si no tienes acceso a tu archivo de configuración de Apache, agrega en tu archivo .htaccess lo siguiente: **Options -Indexes**

***La opción Indexes indica que se deberá mostrar el índice de contenido del directorio en ausencia de un archivo index.html***

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más especifico y decirnos como esto ayudaría a solucionar el problema del autor?

Comment: SI PERO EN ESA CARPETA SE CREAN OTRA CARPETAS Y COMO PONER UN INDEX EN TODAS POR ESO ESTOY BUSCANDO OTRA FORMA

Comment: Puedes modificar el archivo de configuración de apache, modificando las directivas de la carpeta o de la aplicación.

Comment: Tienes acceso al archivo de configuración de tu servidor?

Answer (score 1):

En tu .htaccess puedes usar:

Deny from All

Y si tu server usa Apache 2.4 usas:

Require all denied

No se si esto es lo que quieres hacer pero soy ciego y no se que tiene la imagen que subiste como ejemplo.

Nota: el .htaccess con las líneas anteriores debe ir solo dentro de la carpeta que quieres denegar al acceso público.

Ahora que si quieres que no aparezca ea clásica vista de navegación por directorio y archivos entonces en el .htaccess de la carpeta pones:
Options -Indexes

Comment: ES QUE ESA CARPETA TENGO OTRAS CARPETAS QUE SE CREAN POR CADA USER NUEVO

Comment: Pero no entiendo entonces, quieres denegar el acceso solo si ponen algo como http://tusitio.com/uploads  
Pero no si ponen http://tusitio.com/uploads/usuario1  
Que es lo que quieres que pase con las sub carpetas exactamente?

Comment: quiero  denegar el acceso esa carpeta y a todas las que esten dento de esa sabe como?

Comment: Entonces si no quieres usar la opción de poner un index en todas las subcarpetas podrías usar lo que te sugerí poniendo un solo .htaccess en la raiz de la carpeta uploads y te denegará el acceso a todo su contenido incluyendo subcarpetas

Comment: como es el code del .htaccess me lo podes pasar porfavor

Comment: solo basta con que agregues una de esas líneas dependiendo si tu server es Apache 2.4 o inferior como lo especifiqué, guardas teniendo cuidado con la codificación y listo, no hace falta nada más. Para estar seguro de no fallar en la codificación del archivo puedes reusar un .htaccess que ya se encuentre en tu server

Comment: gracias si me fuciono muchas gracias amig o/a

Comment: Es amigo, jeje, soy chico, si consideras entonces que es la respuesta márcala como aceptada por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Globalmente se hace en la configuración de tu webserver. En el caso de apache por ejemplo sacas `Indexes` de una línea en la configuración que se ve así:

```
Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

La variante `Options - Indexes` se usa en `.htaccess`.

Si usas otro servidor web tienes que consultar la documentación, `nginx`por ejemplo no usa `.htaccess`.

Y al fin tampoco es tanto trabajo de seguir a un `mkdir /var/www/ruta` con un `touch /var/www/ruta/index.html`, si te basta con una pagina vacía.